# Why is my asp.net mvc form POSTing instead of GETting?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, forms, post, get

My code is straightforward enough:

```
    <% using(Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Get)) %>
    <% { %>
        Search for in Screen Name and Email: <%: Html.TextBox("keyword", Request.QueryString["keyword"]) %>
        <button type=submit>Search</button>
    <% } %>
```

The issue I'm running into is that when I submit this form, the values are not added to the querystring. Instead, it appears that the form is submitting by a post request. When I look at the generated HTML, I have this:

```
    <form action="/find/AdminMember/MemberList" method="post">
        Search for in Screen Name and Email: <input id="keyword" name="keyword" type="text" value="" />
        <button type=submit>Search</button>
    </form>
```

Does anyone know why? This seems pretty simple and straighforward to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct signature of the [BeginForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460344.aspx) helper is this:

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm("SomeAction", "SomeController", FormMethod.Get)) %>
<% { %>
    Search for in Screen Name and Email: 
    <%: Html.TextBox("keyword", Request.QueryString["keyword"]) %>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
<% } %>
```

When you write `BeginForm(FormMethod.Get)` you are basically invoking [this signature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470793.aspx) where the `routeValues` parameter has nothing to do with `FormMethod.Get` and which uses POST as default verb.

Comment: ok... I wish they made `using(Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Get))` work. Posts work without explicitly specifying an action and controller. I don't understand why GETs don't. I would think it should at least throw a runtime error.

Comment: it's super annoying, but if you look at all of the overloads there's really no way to do it.

Comment: @quakkels, there isn't such an overload built-in but you could easily write an extension method to achieve the same task.

Answer (score 3):

You're passing `FormMethod.Get` as the `routeValues` parameter

You will have to qualify your `action` and `controller` to set the `FormMethod` of the form tag

```
using(Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", FormMethod.Get))
```

[FormExtensions.BeginForm Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492719%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Looks as if you are not using the correct overload for BeginForm, check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform.aspx) for the various overloads.